# Typegoose not working with vuetify in electron

Tags: mongoose, vuejs2, electron, typegoose

Im trying to build a very simple model with typegoose inside Vue + electron.

This is my simplified code:

```js
import { getModelForClass, prop, modelOptions } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

@modelOptions({ 
                schemaOptions: { collection: 'ability_group' }
              })
export class RmfCategoryGroup2 {

  @prop( {type: () => String} )
  public name: string;
}

export const CategoryGroup2DAO = getModelForClass(RmfCategoryGroup2);
```

When app launches in electron, the window opens and i have an error:

```html
Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
    at addModelToTypegoose (typegoose.ts:180)
    at getModelForClass (typegoose.ts:87)
    at Module../src/model/RmfCategoryGroup.ts (RmfCategoryGroup.ts:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61)
    at Module../src/services/category_groups_service.ts (categories_service.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61)
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-41[0].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/views/admin/category-groups/list.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& (form.vue?58cc:74)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24)
```

If i activate debug on typegoose i have the following traces before error:

```html
Assigning global Schema Options to "TimeStamps"
globalOptions.ts:27 "parseENV" got called
globalOptions.ts:14 "setGlobalOptions" got called with Object
globalOptions.ts:20 new Global Options: Object
prop.ts:50 Added "RmfCategoryGroup2.name" to the Decorator Cache
utils.ts:569 Assigning global Schema Options to "RmfCategoryGroup2"
typegoose.ts:127 buildSchema called for "RmfCategoryGroup2"
schema.ts:49 _buildSchema Called for RmfCategoryGroup2 with options: Object
processProp.ts:471 Detecting PropType
processProp.ts:40 Starting to process "RmfCategoryGroup2.name"
processProp.ts:62 Prop Option "type" is set to  ƒ type() {
    return String;
  }
utils.ts:657 Final getType: dim: 0, type: ƒ type() {
    return String;
  }
typegoose.ts:127 buildSchema called for "type"
utils.ts:569 Assigning global Schema Options to "type"
schema.ts:49 _buildSchema Called for type with options: Object
typegoose.ts:127 buildSchema called for "type"
schema.ts:49 _buildSchema Called for type with options: Object
```

The version im using are:

electron: 11.2.1
node: 14.7.6
vue: 2.6.14
typescript: 4.5.5
typegoose: 5.11.97
mongoose: 6.3.1
vuetify: 2.6.4

im using mongoose-extend-schema: 1.0.0 in another part of app

My tsconfig.ts

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    //"target": "esnext",
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

typegoose version 9.8.1
Thanks!!

Comment: what is your tsconfig? also something seems to be wrong without typegoose version, such a version does not exist

Comment: typegoose/typegoose: 9.8.1

Comment: i dont see anything wrong with the code and tsconfig provided, what compiler / transformer is used with what options?

Comment: npm 8.5.4
tsc 4.1.3
ts-loader 8.2.0
vue 2.6.14
vuetify 2.6.4
eslint 7.32.0
electron 13.0.0
typescript 4.5.5